# What does 'sign' mean in an equation?

Tags: notation

I'm curious what `sign` means in the context of mathematical notation. I'm reading a paper right now and it uses:

$$ sign \overrightarrow{\lambda} \cdot \overrightarrow{a} $$

Is that equivalent to $\pm$ ?

I've never seen this before.

Thanks.

Comment: probably signum, which is $1$ if the argument is positive, $-1$ if the argument is negative, and $0$ if the argument is exactly $0.$

Comment: It is used as the $\large{\tt sgn}$ function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value $\operatorname{sign}(x)$ equals $-1$, $0$, or $1$ depending upon whether the value $x$ is negative, zero, or positive. Sometimes this is written as $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ as is the case [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.